# Nesting image on top another in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to nest an image on top of another (using twitter bootstrap) the problem is when I re-size my browser, the arrow image isn't consistently located (see the image)

It was supposed to be:

[image]

but when the browser re-sized:

[image]

and the code is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div>
            <img alt="" src="../images/fulltime.png" class="img-responsive" />
            <img alt="" src="../images/arrow.png" class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 341px" />
            <label style="position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 43px; font-size: 19px; font-family: Trebuchet MS;
                color: White;">
                Professional
            </label>
            <p style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 25px; font-size: 13px;">
                random text
                <br />
                random text
                <br />
                random text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What did I do wrong here? Or is it not possible?

Note: I just changing my recent web with bootstrap, so I'm new to this stuff and I use bootstrap v3 if it helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution, just add `img-responsive` class, inside the `<div class="col-lg-4">` tag

making it `<div class="col-lg-4 img-responsive">`

the image stays 'intact' now no matter how the browser screen are re-sized, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are using `top: 170px; left: 341px` or saying go 341px in from the left and 170px down from the top. If you position it using bottom and right instead of top and left, then it will anchor to the bottom right corner and you will be saying "So many px from the bottom and so many from the right"

So instead of:

```
<img alt="" src="../images/arrow.png" class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 341px" />
```

Have something like:

```
<img alt="" src="../images/arrow.png" class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; right: 19px" />
```

Change the numbers to suit but note the `top` is now `bottom` and `left` is now `right`

Comment: sorry, but i miss out your point and your answer, can you explain it? :)

Comment: thanks for the solution, but there's is a problem at a certain moment when the browser re-size, take a look here http://postimg.org/image/rnv4qyo4n/

Comment: Give your div a fixed size.